# jquery remove/hide an element (delete button) when one instance of clone elements remain

Tags: jquery, filter, clone, parent-child, show-hide

**Task** Clone a div element (.cloneable) and its child form elements, show hidden anchor that allows the user to remove instances of div.cloneable.

**Problem**  I want to hide the anchor (id dltBtn) once there is only once instance of .cloneable remaining.

**Attempted solutions** I have tried to modify the filters and selectors on .cloneable or make it so that it only hides once their is one instance left but to no avail.

Finally, I want to be able to loop through the input elements, reset them and modify their ids.

Code is below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#dltBtn').hide();
        $('#addBtn').click(function() {
            $('#dltBtn').show();
            var c = $('.nestedDiv').find('.cloneable:first').clone(true);
        // Loop through inputs under cloneable
        // resetId, reset value will go here stubbed out for now
        $('.cloneable:last').after(c);                  
        });         
        $('#dltBtn').click(function() {
        if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
           $(this).closest('.cloneable').remove();
           $('#dltBtn:last').hide($('.cloneable:child').length  == 0 );
        } else {
             $('#dltBtn:parent').hide($('.cloneable').length  == 1);
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: ` $('.cloneable:last').after(c);                  
        })` lacks a semicolon

Comment: Thanks, ianace.  Fixed.  I actually omitted when leaving out extraneous content.

Answer (score 1):

> Finally, I want to be able to loop through the input elements, reset them and modify their ids.

```
clone.find(':input').val('').attr('id', function(index, oldId) { 
   return oldId + index;
})
```